# getting error #1146 on my table after Xampp upgrade

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I did an upgrade of Xampp to version 1.8.3-1
In phpMyAdmin, I can see my databases and the tables in them on the list on the left side. 
But if I click any of my tables, I get and error #1146 table doesn't exist.

It is probably some kind of user access issue. But I haven't changed anything. I'm logging as root/no pw  on mysql.

any idea?

thanks,
Benoit

Comment: ok, gave up... luckily I have TimeMachine, so I restored the old Xampp and everything is back to normal ... except that I don't have the latest Phpmyadmin :(

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the version of XAMPP you also chnaged the version of MySQL.
A straight copy of databases will probably not work.

You either need to backup under the old version and restore into the new version or use the mysql_upgrade processor.

Look up usage of mysql upgrade here [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html)

You will need to find the page relating to the from-version and to-version of MySQL. It may even be required to go via a number of other versions of MySQL. So the backup and restore option os a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Simple upgradation wont help, Following two steps will help you out:

1. Before upgrade , Go to the directory xampp/mysql/data ( or whatever is relevant to your OS) , and copy all the files starting with word ib, like ib_logfil0 etc. and paste to the upgraded version after upgrade.
2. Go to mysql command line, and run this command:

> mysql_upgrade